# Show modal on submit form

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

Here's the code of an Angular 4 component used to collect contact information from visitors:

*.html:*

```
<form (submit)="onCreateContact()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contactname" name="contactname" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="contactemail" name="contactemail" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contactphone" name="contactphone" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#addContactModal'>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addContactModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addContactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addContactModalLabel">Contact</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*.ts:*

```
onCreateContact() {
    let contact = {
        contactname: this.contactname,
        contactemail: this.contactemail,
        contactphone: this.contactphone
    }

    return this.http.post('api/contacts/add', contact).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.success) {
            console.log(data);
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to add contact');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

All contact fields are required; the data is not passed to the backend if not all fields are filled.
Currently, the Bootstrap modal popups every time I press the submit button, even when the data is not passed. How can I show it only when the data is actually passed to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are toggling the modal when the user clicks on the submit button.

What you need to do is, toggle the modal from component class(.ts) after getting the response from the backend.

So in your ".ts" file add below line under the imports section

```
declare var $: any;
```

Then toggle modal after receiving response from backend as below

```
onCreateContact() {
    return this.http.post('api/contacts/add', contact).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.success) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#addContactModal').modal('show'); // Add this line
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to add contact');
            $('#errorModalId').modal('show'); // If you are planning to show error modal when something goes wrong.
        }
    });
}
```

Don't forget to remove data-toggle and data-target attribute from submit button.

Hope this helps.